# Floating an element left after two elements floated right?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm having a problem with floating DIVs. I would like to position four DIVs like this:

[image]

My current code:

```
<div style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <form>
        <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: lightpink;">div 1</div>

        <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 200px; height: 300px; background-color: lightgreen;">div 2</div>

        <div style="float: right; clear: right; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: lightgrey;">div 4</div>
    </form>

    <form>
        <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: lightblue;">div 3</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Positions them like this:

[image]

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLcwU/1/

As you can see, div 3 will not go any higher than div 4.

Question #1: Why is this happening?

Question #2: div's 1, 2, and 4 are inside of one form, while div 3 is in another. Therefore, I can't float div 3 left before floating div 4 right (which fixes the problem for whatever reason). How can I get this working the way I want it to?

EDIT: the lower right div 2 is supposed to be div 4. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: You would need to swap 3 & 4 around for 3 to go higher.

Comment: @Vector - I can't though, because that would result in a form inside a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's happening because you are clearing below the green div. Any floating elements after that will be (at least) below that line, regardless if they are floating to the left or right.

You can put the two divs on the right inside another div that you float right. That means that you don't need to clear the second div, so clearing the blue div will place it below the pink div:

```
<div style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <form>
        <div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: lightpink;">div 1</div>

        <div style="float:right">

            <div style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background-color: lightgreen;">div 2</div>

            <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: lightgrey;">div 2</div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form>
        <div style="float: left; clear: left; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: lightblue;">div 3</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wKVr/

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! It doesn't really make sense to me that a `clear:right` should affect an element being floated left, though. Do you know of a reference where I can learn more about this issue?

Comment: @Nate: Here is the CSS specification of the `clear` property: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control

Answer (score 0):

The way I would try to solve this would be to take each vertical pair of containers and put them inside their own container div.  Now those two outer divs can be floated left and right with clearing or simply make them each width:50% so that they just fill the width of the parent. Then set the outer container divs css to have `text-align: right`, and left respectively. Then set the inner four containers (two in each outer) to be `display:block;`  Then, they will sit underneath eachother with a tiny margin between them; 15px I think. Which you can fix with `margin-top:-.938em;`